# Proving that a product of Riemannian Manifolds is locally conformally flat

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

I like to proof an embedding Theorem for LCF-Manifolds. But im stuck on a little detail. The setting is the following.
Given a locally conformally flat Manifold with Boundary. I want to attach a Cylinder around the Boundary and proof that this Product is LCF- Compatibel in the sense that $\partial M \times  (-1,1)$ is LCF.
So the question is if we can locally extend the Metric past the boundary $\partial M $ to a conformally flat metric on $\partial M \times  (-1,1) $.
I tried using Warped Products for this but it was pointed out to me that if a Warped Product $W= M \times _{f} I   , I \epsilon \mathbb {R}$
is LCF than M has to be a Manifold of constant curvature. This however is to restrictive for my purpose. Does any one else have an idea how to Proof that $\partial M \times  (-1,1) $ is LCF?
Thanks for any Help and sorry for my bad english i hope my question became clear.

Comment: What is your definition of a LCF manifold with boundary? I also do not understand what metric do you put on the product. Lastly, do you know about developing maps?

Comment: I am using the following Definition: A LCF manifold with boundary is a manifold such that every point on the boundary admits a neighborhood conformally diffeomorphic to the Euclidean half ball. The other points admit a neighborhood conformally diffeomorphic to the Euclidean ball. My first guess was just to use the induced Product Metric. And I only know the basic facts about developing maps however i do not understand why u think they can be usefull here, maybe u can elaborate on this

Comment: The first exercise to do here is to compute the image of each boundary component of the universal cover of $M$ under the developing map. I do not think you can solve this problem using tools of Differential Geometry. Developing maps will get you there, eventually.